# why cv2.VideoCapture read() method doesn't return frame, if the ret is True?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I'm trying to get the frame first, so I can identify a face from it, (using my computer webcam)
but when I'm calling the `read()` method, it crashes. saying `tuple index out of range`.
I figured that's because the first frame I give it to detect from is empty.
so it has nothing to turn into a tuple.
but the guy im learning from (course my teacher gave me), he does it, and it works for him.

my code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

ret, frame = cap.read() --> ret is True, but frame is just [[[000,000]]] (and so on with the '0')
print(ret)
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('DATA/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
face_rects = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(frame,scaleFactor=1.2,minNeighbors=5)
print(face_rects)

(face_x,face_y,w,h) = tuple(face_rects[0]) --> crashes here saying "tuple index out of range"
track_window = (face_x,face_y,w,h)
roi = frame[face_y:face_y+h,face_x:face_x+w]

hsv_roi = cv2.cvtColor(roi, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

roi_hist = cv2.calcHist([hsv_roi], [0], None, [180], [0, 180])

cv2.normalize(roi_hist, roi_hist, 0, 255, cv2.NORM_MINMAX)

term_crit = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS | cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_COUNT, 10, 1)

while True:

ret, frame = cap.read()

if ret == True:
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    dst = cv2.calcBackProject([hsv], [0], roi_hist, [0, 180], 1)

    ret, track_window = cv2.meanShift(dst, track_window, term_crit)

    x, y, w, h = track_window
    img2 = cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 0, 255), 5)

    cv2.imshow("img", img2)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == 27:
        break
else:
    break
```

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically it is [[0000]].... returning black frames in the beginning. This will be mostly because of your USB webcam , as it takes more time to load initially. Since your professor might be using a different hardware in different environment, he may not have this issue as it loads up quick and sends the frames. What you can do is either sleep for couple of seconds based on trial and error or you you can just ignore first couple of frames based some *count non zero methods* like `np.count_nonzero()`

Comment: thank you :) I used the `sleep()` method and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

`tuple(face_rects[0])` --> `making tuple(face_rects[00])` worked for me.